# How to convert Formatted Date (yyyy-MM-dd) to Unix time in Java?

Tags: java, date, unix-timestamp

How to convert Formatted date (yyyy-MM-dd) to Unix time in Java?

I want to declare a date using

```
    Date birthday = new Date(y_birthday, m_birthday, d_birthday);
```

but this constructor has been deprecated, so I got to use the other constructor which uses Unix timestamp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, you have the date as a string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`? Use a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse it into a `java.util.Date` object:

```
String text = "2011-12-12";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = df.parse(text);
```

*edit* If you need a `java.sql.Date`, then you can easily convert your `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date`:

```
java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: actually its for Date in java.sql.Date

Comment: @Jesper's answer is correct, also, java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a calendar object if you want more control of the date object

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // indexed month (December)
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 12);
Date date = new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
```

The hours, minutes, seconds etc of the current time will be set though so you may want to set those to 0 (manually per field)

If you're using Java 7 then I think there's some much nicer stuff you can use for handling dates