# How to convert “YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss” to UNIX timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

Or, maybe you know a better approach how to solve this problem. I get dates in the format of "YYYY—MM-DD HH:MM:SS" and need to calculate time difference between now then in approximate increments: 1 minute ago, 1 hour ago, etc.

Any pointers much appreciated :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476147/how-to-convert-formatted-date-yyyy-mm-dd-to-unix-time-in-java?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert date in format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" to UNIX timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704325/how-to-convert-date-in-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-unix-timestamp)

Comment: @JBNizet That's javascript.

Comment: Oh, right. Then see one of the other gazillions similar posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476147/how-to-convert-formatted-date-yyyy-mm-dd-to-unix-time-in-java?rq=1 for example.

Comment: sorry for asking something similar to many other posts but none of other answers seemed to offer exactly what I needed. Got my solution now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You can define your pattern and parse it into a Java Date Object:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("your string goes here");
long timestamp = date.getTime();
```

The first line defines the SimpleDateFormat (can also be static if you reuse it a lot)
The second line parses your input
The third line converts it into milliseconds.

Comment: works great with a slight modification to "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse your date string to a `Date` and then get the timestamp from that:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

final String myDateString = "someDateString";
final Date date = dateFormat.parse(myDateString);

final long timestamp = date.getTime();
```

Have a look at the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadocs for information on which format string to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string into java.util.Date with the assistance of SimpleDateFormat (for examples see - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simpledateformat+%5Bjava%5D) and then get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

```
Date dt = new Date();
long unixTimeStamp = dt.getTime();
```