# Converting Java.util date to XML date in format YYYY-MMM-dd

Tags: java, datetime

I'm using below code to convert java.util.date to XML date

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar toXMLDate(Date dte) {
    try {

        // this may throw DatatypeConfigurationException
                    DatatypeFactory datatypeFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                    // reset all fields
                    calendar.clear();

        Calendar parsedCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        parsedCalendar.setTime(dte);
        calendar.set( parsedCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR ), 
                                 parsedCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                 parsedCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE ));
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCalendar = datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar( calendar );
        xmlCalendar.setTimezone( DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED );
        xmlCalendar.setFractionalSecond( null );
        return xmlCalendar;
```

}

I need to get the date in the format YYYY-MMM-dd, but it returns in a format YYYY-MM-dd.
Can anyone tell me how can i change the format?
Thanks

Comment: [`SimpleDateFormat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = formate.parse("your string goes here");
long timestamp = date.getTime();
```

[How to convert “YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss” to UNIX timestamp in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322780/how-to-convert-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-unix-timestamp-in-java)

Comment: I'm able to format java date ,the issue is when i convert it from Java util date to XMLGregorian calendar date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()
              .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
              .toLocalDate()
              .toString()
```

> 2017-01-23

## Details

No such thing as an `XML date`. Perhaps you mean the date-time formats defined in [XML Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) by the W3C. These formats are amongst those defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, and are used by the java.time classes by default when parsing/generating strings.

Your Question is confused, asking for a String yet showing code that generates an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object. **Date-time objects such as `XMLGregorianCalendar` do *not* have a format.** Such date-time objects store information, not text. You may ask such objects to *generate* a String object whose text represents the value within the object. But the String and the date-time object are entirely distinct and separate.

Avoid legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `Calendar`, etc. These are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The equivalent of `java.util.Date` is `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). You may convert by calling new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

You want to work with only the date portion, without a time-of-day. So extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

Your desired format complies with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for date-time text. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2017-01-23

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).